# My some Pod is Failing due to ImagePullBackOff while applying ResourceQuota with namespace

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces

Hi i have scenario where we are creating multiple environments in different namespaces so for this we are we are creating ResourceQuota per each namespace But after deploying pod in namespace my some pod is getting failed due to ImagePullBackOff. If i don't apply ResourceQuota then all pod run fine.But we need to implement ResourceQuota for our situation because we are going in multi tenant architecture in single cluster. here are more details
My resource yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1

kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: new-name
spec:
  hard:
    requests.cpu: "20"
    requests.memory: 150Gi
    limits.cpu: "20"
    limits.memory: 150Gi
```

Kubectl get pod -n <my-namespace>

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpCft.png)

Also my worker node have enough resource
kubectl describe node <my-node-name>

```
 Resource                    Requests       Limits
  --------                    --------       ------
  cpu                         13725m (86%)   13400m (84%)
  memory                      80508Mi (64%)  105400Mi (84%)
  ephemeral-storage           0 (0%)         0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi               0 (0%)         0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi               0 (0%)         0 (0%)
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs  0              0
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age                  From     Message
  ----     ------                 ----                 ----     -------
  Warning  EvictionThresholdMet   7m4s (x20 over 9d)   kubelet  Attempting to reclaim ephemeral-storage
  Normal   NodeHasDiskPressure    6m58s (x19 over 9d)  kubelet  Node ip-10-200-10-157.ec2.internal status is now: NodeHasDiskPressure
  Normal   NodeHasNoDiskPressure  112s (x21 over 10d)  kubelet  Node ip-10-200-10-157.ec2.internal status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
```

So if i don't use resourceQuota then image pull successfully.
Please let me know if there is any limitation of ResourceQuoata here.
Thanks in advance

kubectl describe pod -n

Normal   Pulling    36s (x4 over 2m10s)  kubelet            Pulling image "393871171186.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/aro-datamodeler-editor:8.1.2303.0-r7ebe2a05e-SNAPSHOT"
Warning  Failed     36s (x4 over 2m10s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image ".dkr.ecr.***.amazonaws.com/aro-datamodeler-editor:8.1.2303.0-r7ebe2a05e-SNAPSHOT": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image ".dkr.ecr.***.amazonaws.com/aro-datamodeler-editor:8.1.2303.0-r7ebe2a05e-SNAPSHOT": failed to resolve reference ".dkr.ecr.***.amazonaws.com/aro-datamodeler-editor:8.1.2303.0-r7ebe2a05e-SNAPSHOT": pulling from host .dkr.ecr.***.amazonaws.com failed with status code [manifests 8.1.2303.0-r7ebe2a05e-SNAPSHOT]: 403 Forbidden

Pod should pull the image

Comment: Please update your question and share output of `kubectl describe pod <imagepull-pod> -n <namespace>`

Comment: updated with event logs but other pod is pulling same image successfully, if i remove ResourceQuota then these pod also pull the image successfully.